# How to copy massive data to clipboard

Tags: autohotkey, clipboard, massive

I have an array [1, 2, 56, 32, 54] or something.

How do i send it to clipboard

> `1
>    2 
>   56 
>   32 
>   54`

I tried this.

```
Loop % table.MaxIndex() {
    meow := table[A_Index]
    Clipboard := meow"`r"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table := [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

vClipboard := ClipboardAll
Clipboard := ""

Loop, % table.Count()
    string := string ? string . ", " . table[A_Index] : table[A_Index]

Clipboard := string

;Do some stuff.

Clipboard := vClipboard ;Restore the Clipboard.
```

Your problem was trying to loop with table.MaxIndex() which will potentially give you an unexpected amount since you can have an array with 2 values but very far apart in terms of Index i.e.

```
table := [1]
table[93] := "String"
```

and also each loop was overwriting your meow value. The method you want to use is concatenate i.e.

```
meow := "Hello"
meow := meow . "World" or meow .= "World"
```